# Changing specific cell color in matlab gui table

Tags: matlab, user-interface, background-color

I'm writing a GUI which contains a table in it.
The table called: "Price_Table" and looks like this:

```
   name     price
1   a         5
2   b        -6
3   c         7
```

How can I make the background color of column "price" to change according to the value in it? for example if the cell contains negative number (like -6) I want the background color to be red, and if it's positive to be green.

At that moment im using:

```
set(handles.Price_Table,'Data',[name price],'backgroundcolor',[1 0 0])
```

but it changes the whole table.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25038-how-to-change-each-cell-color-in-a-uitable) and [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitable-cell-colors/) can be of help to you.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Is there an option to do it without java? just like choosing specific cell (1,2) and color its background? If not, can you please explain what javaaddpath is for my code?

Comment: Sorry for this late answer, did you try the solution proposed [in the first of the two links](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25038-how-to-change-each-cell-color-in-a-uitable)? It works fine and without java.

Comment: html did the job i used:                                                                       colergen = @(color,text) ['<html><table border=0 width=400 bgcolor=',color,'><TR><TD>',text,'</TD></TR> </table></html>'];       data{indexx,indexy}=colergen('#00FF00',num2str(data{indexx,indexy}));thanks for your respond, the link were useful.